# What is the difference between dB queries offset and skip

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I am currently using mongodb as database of large rails application.What is the difference  between dB queries skip and offset

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb offers two approaches to batch processing when you want to use paged results. First is skip which you will usually call as cursor.skip(n) where n tells it to skip n documents.

For e.g. db.collection.find().skip(4) // skip 4 documents

The other approach would be to use limit which strictly restricts the output to the number you provide.

For e.g. db.collection.find().limit(10)  // Limits output to 10 documents

If you want to efficiently use a batch operation use both consecutively:

db.collection.find().skip(10).limit(10)

This way you can implement pagination by skipping a page of 10 documents while simultaneously restricting the output to 10 documents.

Comment: As mongoid document suggested using skip can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

As per per pymongo's irc channel #mongoengine on freenode there is no difference.Infact I could not find such thing called offset in mongoid document.Also skip should be avoided as much as possible.when you "skip" results, it still needs to calculate them to skip them.  This is wasteful, and exhibits log n performance the higher the page number (as the full index of all matched records needs to be walked).  Using a $gt query to match "everything after what has already been seen" allows MongoDB to properly use the index.